# Flutter - When add border radius border disappear

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter and I am trying to make a dynamic icon button.
for that I add following decoration

```
      Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0),
        width: 150,
        height: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: AppColors.primaryColor),
            bottom: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: AppColors.primaryColor),
            right: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: AppColors.primaryColor)
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(12.0)),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            this.iconText,
            style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.primaryTextColor),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

But when I add this 'borderRadius' border disappear and when I comment 'borderRadius' border appear. Could I know the reason for that? and How can I use borderRadius without border disappe

Comment: What do you want to do exactly?

Comment: I want add a border with border radius to a container

Comment: The problem is not with `borderRadius`, you need to complete the border on all sides otherwise it won't work

Comment: Yes it is working when I add borders on all sides. But actually I want border on only three sides and I don't want left side border to appear. what should I do?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**You have to Add Border from all side**

```
  Container(
        margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0),
        width: 150,
        height: 50,
        decoration: BoxDecoration(
          border: Border(
            top: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: AppColors.primaryColor),
            bottom: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: AppColors.primaryColor),
            right: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: AppColors.primaryColor),
             left: BorderSide(width: 2.0, color: AppColors.primaryColor)
          ),
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(12.0)),
        ),
        child: Center(
          child: Text(
            this.iconText,
            style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.primaryTextColor),
          ),
        ),
      ),
```

**Or** this

```
Container(
            margin: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 45.0),
            width: 150,
            height: 50,
            decoration: BoxDecoration(
              border: Border.all(width: 2.0, color: Theme.of(context).primaryColor),
              borderRadius: BorderRadius.only(
                  topRight: Radius.circular(12.0)),
            ),
            child: Center(
              child: Text(
                this.iconText,
                style: TextStyle(color: AppColors.primaryTextColor), //Whatever color you want 
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: Thanks, Yes it is working when I add borders on all sides. But actually I want border on only three sides and I don't want left side border to appear. what should I do?

Comment: @Rukshan did you try removing the left side width

Comment: Oh thanks, It works with removing the left side width, I didn't try that way previously, I did only remove left: BorderSide..

Comment: @Rukshan Great glad to help you :)